# Ruby and Webrick Video Streaming

Tags: ruby, html, webrick

I am developing a web-app that will stream a database of videos, but I am having difficulties with Webbrick and HTML5 Video. I am using a simple HTML tag but the video won't seem to show up. any help ? (the file path is correct btw).

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<div id="lr_video">

<%= video_tag (["videos/final_video.mp4", "final_video.ogg", "movie.webm"], :size => "320x240", :controls => true, :autobuffer => true) %>

</div>
```

my Ruby code:

in config/application.rb:

```
...
..
    #HTML5 Video !!!
    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/public/assets/videos"

..
...
```

now I am using Webrick as a production server, and I put my videos under "/public/assets/videos" but the video doesn't show up

any help ?

Comment: try <%= video_tag (["assets/final_video.mp4", "final_video.ogg", "movie.webm"], :size => "320x240", :controls => true, :autobuffer => true) %>

Comment: try <%= video_tag (["final_video.mp4", "final_video.ogg", "movie.webm"], :size => "320x240", :controls => true, :autobuffer => true) %>

Answer (score 1):

You are probably sending the video with the wrong Content-Type header.

Check the output of

```
curl -I http://localhost:3000/assets/final_video.mp4 | grep Content-Type
```

It should say

```
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

If if does not, then you should fix the generation of the content-type header.

Comment: You need to adapt that line to your setup up; something like `curl -I http://devserver:8012/TheSite/videos/final_video.mp4'.

Comment: ok I tried this,'curl -I http://0.0.0.0:3000/public/assets/videos/final_video.mp4' and webrick returns me this: 'ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/public/assets/videos/final_video.mp4"):' how can this happen since I defined it above?

Comment: The URI path is either `/assets/final_video.mp4` or `/assets/videos/final_video.mp4`, not `/public/videos/...`. So try `http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/final_video.mp4`.

Comment: great, I now got, 'Content-Type: video/mp4', but the video won't show again.

Comment: Can you make sure that the `<video>` tag has been created correctly in the HTML page? Also, try setting only one source file, not an array of source files (just to remove possible problem sources).

Comment: BTW, if you are testing with MP4 files only, make also sure to use a browser that includes codec for such format, Safari in other words.

Comment: Any progress on this? Have the exact same problem, tried everything, no luck :(